# Circular stacked barplot in R - Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (26)

Tags: r, bar-chart, polar-coordinates

I am trying to create a circular stacked barplot as mentioned here (https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html). And I get the following error when when I get to the step of making the plot (in bold below):

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (26): hjust
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 208 rows containing missing values (position_stack).

This is what my data looks like (with 5 columns and 70 rows):

**Individual; group; value1; value2; value3; value4**

**Here are my codes:**

## Transform data in a tidy format (long format)

```
data <- data %>% gather(key = "observation", value="value", -c(1,2))
```

## Make the plot

```
p <- ggplot(data) +

  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=observation), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) + 

  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 0, xend = start, yend = 0), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 2, xend = start, yend = 2), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 4, xend = start, yend = 4), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 6, xend = start, yend = 6), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 8, xend = start, yend = 8), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),5), y = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8), label = c("0", "2", "4", "6", "8") , color="grey", size=6 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +

  ylim(-150,max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() +  

 geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=tot+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

 geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +

  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE) 

 **ggsave(p, file="output1.png", width=10, height=10)**
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!!

**individual    group   value1  value2  value3  value4**

`Biomarker1 Group1  0   1   2   2
Biomarker2  Group2  0   1   0   2
Biomarker3  Group2  0   1   0   1
Biomarker4  Group3  1   2   1   0
Biomarker5  Group4  0   2   4   1
Biomarker6  Group4  0   1   0   1
Biomarker7  Group4  0   1   0   1
Biomarker8  Group5  0   1   0   1
Biomarker9  Group6  0   1   1   1
Biomarker10 Group6  0   2   1   1`

Comment: Are you using the same simulated data from that post?

Comment: Hi there! We can help you a lot better if you both (a) narrow down the problem and (b) make your example reproducible. For (a), comment out all `geom`s in your plot. Then go through 1 at a time uncommenting them and running the plot code until you find the error. Since your error mentions "position stack", it's probably the `geom_bar` line... Then, for (b), you shared ~20 lines of data manipulation code for data we don't have. And it doesn't really matter what you did to the data before you plot it - all that matters is the data you tried to plot....

Comment: So, when you figure out which line causes the error, share with us just that data. The nicest way to share data is with `dput()` because it is copy/pasteable. If the problem is your `geom_bar` line, which uses the `data` (not `base_data` or `label_data` or `grid_data`), enter `dput(data[1:20, ])` in your console and edit the result into your question. That will us the first 20 rows to test solutions on. (Of course, use a different subset if the first 20 rows don't illustrate the problem.)

Comment: And, when you edit, you can shorten the question by removing all the data wrangling, etc. That will make your question a lot more approachable and more focused, and you'll get help much faster.

Comment: Your code works for me on R4.0.0 with ggplot2 3.3.0

Comment: So, I have provided in the #dput(data[1:20, ]) in my question above. @Edward, it runs for me as well using the same codes if I were to have 3 columns as shown in the tutorial but my dataset have 4 columns of values. In addition, the values in tutorial range above 50...meanwhile my values range betwen 0-15.

Comment: You need to post your _original_ data, not the final data. I suspect the problem may be in your `gather` function but it's hard to know without having your data.

Comment: Hi @Edward, thanks for the reply. I have pasted my data above in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the modified code from the linked post to produce a circular barplot with angled group labels in the centre.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=c( rep('Group A', 10), rep('Group B', 30), rep('Group C', 14), rep('Group D', 6)) ,
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 3
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar)
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group)
data$id <- seq(1, nrow(data))

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar 
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))
```

---

This is the additional code to create the angles for the group labels

```
angle <- 90 - 360 * (base_data$title-0.5)/number_of_bar  
base_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)
```

---

```
# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar

  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +

# Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 80, xend = start, yend = 80), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 60, xend = start, yend = 60), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 40, xend = start, yend = 40), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 20, xend = start, yend = 20), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),4), y = c(20, 40, 60, 80), label = c("20", "40", "60", "80") , color="grey", size=3 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +

  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  ylim(-50,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
#    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +

  coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

# Add base line information
geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -1, xend = end, yend = -1), colour = "black", alpha=0.6, size=0.8, inherit.aes = F ) +
```

---

And here we utilize the angle:

```
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -6, label=group, angle=angle), 
            hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.7, size=2, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There were many issues here. The first two are serious and concern use of "hard_coding". That is, the code does not depend on the data. The second two are minor problems with your data, not the code.

1. The `hjust` argument: `geom_text(data=base_data, aes(...), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), ...`
2. The y-axis limits: `ylim(-150, max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T))`
3. The data are highly skewed.
4. You have too many bars and too many groups.

Number 1 causes the error:

```
# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (24): hjust
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

In the linked post, the `base_data` looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  group start   end title
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     8   4.5
2 B        11    38  24.5
3 C        41    52  46.5
4 D        55    58  56.5
```

But for your data it looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 4
   group   start   end title
   <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Group1      1    -1   0  
 2 Group10     2     1   1.5
 3 Group11     4     5   4.5
 4 Group12     8     8   8  
 5 Group13    11     9  10  
 6 Group14    12    42  27  
 7 Group15    45    43  44  
 8 Group16    46    47  46.5
 9 Group17    50    49  49.5
10 Group18    52    52  52  
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Therefore the `hjust` argument needs to be changed to something that depends on the data, and not hard-coded with values. Perhaps just omit it and see what the graph looks like and change it if required.

Number 2 is not serious but causes your graph to have a large hole in the centre. The value of -150 was based on the data, so this (hard-coding) is bad practice. It looks like the minimum y-axis value should be changed to `-max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)`, which is now more general. But this may need some tinkering to get the best result. The ideal value may also depend on the number of bars and the skewness of the data.

There are other parts where hard-coding was also used.

Number 3 is not serious but causes some of the labels to appear off the plotting region. You can try to transform the y-axis, but I'll leave that to you to decide.

Number 4 is not serious either but causes the labels within the inner circle to overlap.

After fixing these and other minor issues, you should get the following:

---

[image]

Comment: Hi @Edward, I got it to work. This was super helpful, thank you so much. Would you know if it is possible to to change colors of bars? For instance, I want to change the yellow to green, and green to orange...etc.

Comment: The third line: `scale_fill_viridis()` determines the colours.

Comment: Right, just need to replace the third line with: withscale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "grey")

Comment: Hi @Edward - I was wondering if you think I am able angle the inside text (Groups) to align with the outside text of biomarker?

Comment: That should be possible.

Comment: I have been trying to change the angle within this code where I have set the angle to 90 but all groups go into 90 degrees as oppose to a clock-like angle similar to the names of biomarkers, so I would really appreciate if you could help me with this. Thanks so much in advance. geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, angle=90, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)

Comment: No no, you have to supply a _variable_ for the angle, similar to the outer labels. Something like: `angle = label_data$angle` but replace label_data with base_data, and you'll have to add the angle values to the base_data data frame first.

Comment: Thanks @Edward - based on your previous comment, I supplied a variable for the angle but half of the labels are not properly aligned. Do you think its because certain groups have more biomarkers than others? Here is my code: base_data$ID <- seq.int(nrow(base_data))
number_of_bars <- nrow(base_data)
angles <- 90 - 360 * (base_data$ID-0.5) /number_of_bars     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
base_data$hjust <- ifelse( angles < -90, 1, 0)
base_data$angles <- ifelse(angles < -90, angles+180, angles)

Comment: How about omitting the word "Group" in the label and just show the numbers?

Comment: I could but the labels are important, as in my actual data, its not called group 1....etc, each group actually has a unique label (so different character length), and it may be too confusing for the reader if I leave in just the numbers. Do you think there is any other way I could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my new answer.