# Circlize circular barplot as in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, circlize, circos

I am trying to duplicate a circular barplot made with ggplot2 into ciclize as follows:
[image: Circular bar plot with ggplot2]

While I can bring it into a scatterplot and add a regression:

[image]

The visualization as barplot interests me more. However I have not found any similar example in the circlize guide or any example. I have tooled with the circos.polygon however drawing each bar seems not the best solution. Thus, I wonder if someone has toyed with this already, while no specific subject existis in stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61721664/circular-stacked-barplot-in-r-aesthetics-must-be-either-length-1-or-the-same-a/61938267#61938267

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Zuguang Gu on twitter and he was kind enough to make a wraper function for circlize. He posted the details here:

https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize/reference/circos.barplot.html

I really like ggplot2 but the level of detail and easy handling for circular barplots made me look for an answer using circlize.

Thanks to all that answered.